# how to make complicatedly nested local variable to global variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, methods, global-variables, local-variables

i need to make some local variable to global to make the program more easy , i tried "window.varname=varname" but it doesn't work in my case , which is like:

```
<script scr=./some_scr><script>

object_1.method_1(a , function(b,c)

{

d = ...
e = ...
new f = object_2.method_2(d , e)

});
```

where a~f are variables,
that i need the variable `f` to be global for other use , but the window.name trick doesn't work in this case... any one can help? thanks!

Comment: `f = object_2.method_2(d , e);` makes `f` global

Comment: Assigning to `window` will work, unless you are trying to overwrite an existing property of `window`. Some of them a special internal behavior.

Comment: dear Felix Kling, I put a line with   `window.yonoodle = f` ,and found the value in the Chrome console , but when I try  `console.log(window.yonoodle);` ,it returns `undefined` , how can i access the window.yonoodle property ? thanks!